# How to find whether a class is applied?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a "particular" class is applied to a span inside a div or not.So i tried

```
$('#div').click(function() {
     console.log($(this).find('.myImgClass').length);  // returns 0-if not found
                                                      // 1 if found
}
```

### HTMl

```
<div>
 <span class="myImgClass"></span>
</div>
```

Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine... there is no right or wrong anyway. Depending on what exactly you want to do, e.g. if you want to filter the `div`s, you can also use `.has`: http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
$('div').click(function() {
  alert("Spans with .myImgClass: " + $(this).children('span.myImgClass').length);
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gw8Wg/)

If you *only* need divs with the class then:

```
$('div > span.myImgClass').click(function() {
  var theSpan = $(this);
  var theDiv = theSpan.parent();
  alert("Div with Span with .myImgClass.");
});
```

Comment: I think `div > span.myImgClass:` should be `div > span.myImgClass`, right? But `$('div > span.myImgClass')` would select the `span` elements, not the `div`s, hence the click event handler is bound to the span elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jQuery.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to do that:

```
var hasMyImgClassClass = $("span").hasClass("myImgClass");
```

Comment: But that does not tell you whether the element *has a descendant* with that class.

Comment: I think he meant `$("div > span")`

Comment: @Erik: Even then, in the context of this click event handler, `.hasClass()` is not particularly  useful. You would have to get a reference to the `span` first in order to use it, e.g. `$(this).find('span')` and why wouldn't use the class name directly in the selector then?

Comment: Mine is only in reference to this answer (which needs more work), not the question.

Comment: @Erik Philips: I had to misunderstood OP intentions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, `div` instead of `#div`

```
$('div').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).has('.myImgClass').length);
});
```

Comment: Note that `.has` returns jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div >span").click(function(){
 alert($(this).hasClass('myImgClass')) 
});
```

Comment: This changes to which element the click event handler is bound to... why are you doing this? It seems the OP wants the click handler bound to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right (apart from the div selector), but if you want to specifically check for spans change it to this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
     console.log($(this).find('span.myImgClass').length);  
});
```